# What's the most abused features in Visual Studio / C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

For me, No.1 has to be code folding.

```
#region xxx
#endregion
```

All of sudden, people find an excuse to have big classes(files) because they can "organize" them nicely. I once saw a half-page-long class with 3,000 lines. I was speechless and they were like "what's the problem"?

No.2 is partial class. It's actually a nice feature especially when you work with generated code. However, some people use it to "break down" a class to multiple pieces. Why? Because that class is so big and popular that it's always locked in the source control. Instead of breaking down the class into different smaller classes, they create multiple files like my_Class1.cs, your_Class1.cs etc so that people can work on Class1 at the same time.

I would like to include "Copy&Paste" but it's not Visual Studio's fault...

Comment: should be community wiki

Comment: None of this is Visual Studio's fault, or the language fault, or the framework's. I find this question argumentative at best.

Comment: Nobody say that VS or C# is to be blamed. The abusing developers probably are.

Comment: Subjective and argumentative.

Comment: partial is actually part of the C# language definition (section 10.2 of the 3.0 specification), not a visual studio feature at all.

Comment: Regions are evil. Hate them every day.

Comment: To clarify, the reason this kind of question needs to be community wiki is because people tend to use down and upvotes to indicate agreement with an answer (e.g. a "me, too") statement, which is reputation abuse in a non-community wiki answer.

Answer (score 2):

Next to `#region` blocks I would say the ASP.NET [IDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.idatasource.aspx) implementations ([`SqlDataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.aspx), [`LinqDataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linqdatasource.aspx)) that force (allow) you to write data-access code directly into your aspx pages. I would not use this even for a really small demo app, but nowhere in the documentation of these classes is it mentioned that for a well-designed application you should not use these classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most abused feature would be using the default templates as is.  Many of the templates include "partial" as well as the regions and include/using statements that aren't required by the code inside of the class.

After that, I'd have to agree with the #region blocks; however, those CAN be useful if done properly.  Usually though they are used as a means to organize classes that are larger than they probably should be.

Answer (score 0):

Not paying attention to Warnings

Comment: Only because there is always sooo many of them...

Answer (score 0):

Graphical editor for WebForms. Spoiled so many potentially good developers into drag-and-drop monkeys.